# copy() still throwing errors with parameter folder_id

Tags: gspread

The [gspread docs specify](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=copy#gspread.Client.copy) that the `copy()` method takes up to four parameters, one of them being an optional `folder_id` into which the newly copied spreadsheet will be created:

However, in attempting to specify `folder_id`

`client.copy(file_id='1iKMBJ56TKxafMGhSbh66mA9GdhCaOONaLI-g3-xo6_Y', title='Test_Copy',  copy_permissions='True', folder_id="1cWSInUwf39NOSTodCTqesc0WeTnp_VKI")`

I am getting a traceback error stating that `folder_id` is not a valid parameter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/gspread_copyTO.py", line 111, in <module>
    client.copy(file_id='1iKMBJ56TKxafMGhSbh66mA9GdhCaOONaLI-g3-xo6_Y', title='Test_Copy',  copy_permissions='True', folder_id="1cWSInUwf39NOSTodCTqesc0WeTnp_VKI")
TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder_id'
```

`folder_id` was supposedly corrected as a missing parameter of `copy()` in [#851](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/851) (which supposedly fixed [#805](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/805),
and [#678](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/678)) and `folder_id` is clearly listed as a parameter in the [docs](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=copy#gspread.Client.copy), so am I missing something or is this still a problem?

Some other items of note: `copy()` does in fact work if no `folder_id` is specified as a parameter, but my situation requires the ability to copy directly to a specific location.

In attempting to omit "folder_id=" (in case some back-end typo was the source of the problem), I called the function with no argument titles

`client.copy('1iKMBJ56TKxafMGhSbh66mA9GdhCaOONaLI-g3-xo6_Y', 'Test_Copy',  'True', '1cWSInUwf39NOSTodCTqesc0WeTnp_VKI')`

and got the strange error of having specified 5 arguments when I clearly only provided 4:

`TypeError: copy() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Lastly, `copy_permissions` accepts both the bool `True` as well as string `'True'` as valid arguments (not sure if this is normal or intended behavior).

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: hi, could it be the package needs to be updated?

Comment: Insofar as pip install is aware, I have the latest package. I wish it were so simple! 
 Are you able to run copy() with a specified folder_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else dealing with this problem, it seems I had fallen through the cracks.

I confirmed that I had the latest version of `gspread` by trying to force an upgrade with

`pip install --upgrade gspread`

but `pip` skipped upgrading all items of the package, since the package was nominally up to date.

I verified that in fact the version was correct (not just that `pip` was refusing to upgrade) by printing

```
print(gspread.__version__)
>>>> 3.7.0
```

If I had just taken Python's word for it, I would have been been stuck.  Instead I decided to dig into the `gspread` code itself and it turns out that the `client.py` file that is included with the latest package download—and contains the definitions for `copy()`—IS NOT the latest code, as found on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/client.py).

I guess I am lucky to have been stubborn enough not to accept Python's word for having the latest and greatest, but it raises the larger question of how to deal with this kind of thing—how DOES one ensure (`gspread` or otherwise) that they are in possession of properly updated code?

Is this a `pip` (or larger `Python`) problem; is it `gspread's` oversight; is there some other place where the misconnect could be occurring; how can I verify what else in my `gspread` package is or is not missing?