# Save google sheet file in specific directory in google drive using Colab

Tags: google-sheets, directory, export, google-colaboratory, drive

In Colab, I haven't could to know how I can export a google sheet file in specific directory in google drive.

I know how I can export .csv and .xlsx to specific directory and
I know how I can export .gsheet to my general drive space

Could you help me with this please?

Thanks you a lot

Answer (score 0):

The method that I provide here assumes that you have no problem in creating a new spreadsheet file in your notebook. You can create the new spreadsheet using the code below:

```
%pip install --upgrade gspread #IMPORTANT

import gspread
print(gspread.__version__) # make sure gspread is of the latest version
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default

auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

sh = gc.create('newSpreadsheetFileName', folder_id='yourFolderID')
wb = gc.open('newSpreadsheetFileName').sheet1
```

After that you should be able to play around inside the first sheet of the workbook `wb`. By play around, I mean you can import the contents of a data frame, list, etc. If you are unfamiliar with handling Gspread items, you can follow the [official documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/client.html#gspread.Client.create). You don't need to move it anymore as it is already created in the folder that you want it to be in.

Advanced notes:

Note that I put an "IMPORTANT" comment beside the pip upgrade line. I include it here because as of writing, the default version of gspread is 3.4.2, which has a bug where you would not be able to input the `folder_id` parameter into the `create()`
or `copy()` function (for further dive in click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68218090/copy-still-throwing-errors-with-parameter-folder-id)). This bug seems to have been fixed in the latest version of `gspread`, so the update is required. FYI, I am currently using version 5.4.0 and everything that I showed you in the code snippet should work fine. It's actually a little odd that Google don't just let us use the latest version of their library out of the box, honestly.

Hopefully this can help!

Cheers